How to sort blogs initially on first render in React?
I am using React 18. I have a Blog application where I can add information to blogs that I find interesting in my app.
When the blog list is initially rendered I get all the blogs from the backend and set the initial blogs. I want to sort my blogs as per most liked blogs first on my initial render; I have tried a few things in the useEffect hook but I keep getting some or the other console errors and warnings. Any help would be appreciated.
Below is my code in my App.jsx file
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Blog from './components/Blog';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';
import NewBlogForm from './components/NewBlogForm';
import Notification from './components/Notification';
import Togglable from './components/Togglable';
import blogService from './services/blogs';
import loginService from './services/login';

const App = () => {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);
  const blogFormRef = useRef();
  const [notification, setNotification] = useState({
    message: '',
    isError: false,
  });
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    blogService.getAll().then((initialBlogs) => setBlogs(initialBlogs));
    // I WANT TO SORT THE BLOGS ON MY FIRST RENDER
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loggedUserJSON = window.localStorage.getItem('loggedBlogappUser');
    if (loggedUserJSON) {
      const user = JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON);
      setUser(user);
      blogService.setToken(user.token);
    }
  }, []);

  const compareBlogs = (a, b) => {
    if (a.likes < b.likes) return 1;
    if (a.likes > b.likes) return -1;
    return 0;
  };

  // THIS IS USED IN UPDATING A BLOG BELOW AND I WANT TO USE IT FOR INITIAL BLOGS AS WELL
  const sortBlogsAsPerMostLikedFirst = (blogs) => {
    const sortedBlogs = blogs.sort(compareBlogs);
    setBlogs(sortedBlogs);
  };

  const removeNotificationAfterFiveSeconds = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setNotification({
        message: '',
        isError: false,
      });
    }, 5000);
  };

  const handleLogin = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const user = await loginService.login({
        username,
        password,
      });

      window.localStorage.setItem('loggedBlogappUser', JSON.stringify(user));

      blogService.setToken(user.token);
      setUser(user);
    } catch (error) {
      setNotification({
        message: error.response.data.error,
        isError: true,
      });
      removeNotificationAfterFiveSeconds();
    }
  };

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    try {
      window.localStorage.removeItem('loggedBlogappUser');
      setUser(null);
      setUsername('');
      setPassword('');
    } catch (exception) {
      console.error(exception.message);
    }
  };

  const addBlog = (blogObject) => {
    blogFormRef.current.toggleVisibility();

    blogService
      .create(blogObject)
      .then((returnedBlog) => {
        setBlogs(blogs.concat(returnedBlog));
        setNotification({
          message: `SUCCESS: Added ${returnedBlog.title} blog`,
          isError: false,
        });
        removeNotificationAfterFiveSeconds();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setNotification({
          message: error.response.data.error,
          isError: true,
        });
        removeNotificationAfterFiveSeconds();
      });
  };

  const increaseLikes = (blogToUpdate) => {
    const blog = blogs.find((b) => b.id === blogToUpdate.id);
    const updatedBlog = { ...blog, likes: blog.likes + 1 };

    blogService
      .update(blog.id, updatedBlog)
      .then((returnedBlog) => {
        const blogList = blogs.map((blog) => blog.id !== blogToUpdate.id ? blog : returnedBlog);
        // USING THE sortBlogsAsPerMostLikedFirst FUNCTION HERE
        sortBlogsAsPerMostLikedFirst(blogList);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setNotification({
          message: `Blog '${blog.title}' was already removed from server`,
          isError: true,
        });
        removeNotificationAfterFiveSeconds();
        const blogList = blogs.filter((b) => b.id !== blogToUpdate.id);
        setBlogs(blogList);
        console.error(error.message);
      });
  };

  const deleteBlog = (blog) => {
    const toDelete = window.confirm(`Delete "${blog.title}" blog?`);
    console.log({ toDelete });

    if (toDelete) {
      blogService
        .deleteBlog(blog)
        .then(() => {
          const blogList = blogs.filter((b) => blog.id !== b.id);
          setBlogs(blogList);
          console.log('Blog deleted');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err.message);
          alert('Sorry! Blog cannot be deleted as it is not created by you.');
        });
    }
  };

  const loginForm = () => {
    return (
      <Togglable buttonLabel="login">
        <LoginForm
          username={username}
          password={password}
          handleUsernameChange={({ target }) => setUsername(target.value)}
          handlePasswordChange={({ target }) => setPassword(target.value)}
          handleSubmit={handleLogin}
        />
      </Togglable>
    );
  };

  const blogForm = () => (
    <Togglable buttonLabel="new blog" ref={blogFormRef}>
      <NewBlogForm createBlog={addBlog} />
    </Togglable>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Blogs</h1>

      <Notification notification={notification} />

      {!user && loginForm()}

      {user && (
        <div>
          <p>
            {user.name} logged in{' '}
            <button type="button" onClick={handleLogout}>
              logout
            </button>
          </p>

          {blogForm()}

          <ul style={{ listStyleType: 'none', padding: 0 }}>
            {blogs.map((blog) => (
              <Blog
                key={blog.id}
                blog={blog}
                loggedInUsername={user.username}
                handleLikes={() => increaseLikes(blog)}
                handleDeleteBlog={() => deleteBlog(blog)}
              />
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

If I do the below, I get a dependency warning:
  useEffect(() => {
    blogService.getAll().then((initialBlogs) => sortBlogsAsPerMostLikedFirst(initialBlogs));
  }, []);

Warning:
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'sortBlogsAsPerMostLikedFirst'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.

If I add the sortBlogsAsPerMostLikedFirst as dependency, my backend infinitely calls the get blogs api.

I found a fix for this issue from the article here: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/
See, "But I Can’t Put This Function Inside an Effect" section in the article. I used the first solution, where he states: "if a function doesn’t use anything from the component scope, you can hoist it outside the component and then freely use it inside your effects"
So below are the modifications I made: (NOTE: Please see comments for where the changes are made)
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Blog from './components/Blog';
...

// MOVED THE FUNCTION OUTSIDE THE APP COMPONENT
const compareBlogs = (a, b) => {
  if (a.likes < b.likes) return 1;
  if (a.likes > b.likes) return -1;
  return 0;
};

// REMOVED THE SETSTATE CODE FROM THE FUNCTION AND MOVED THIS FUNCTION OUTSIDE THE APP COMPONENT
const sortBlogsAsPerMostLikedFirst = (blogs) => {
  const sortedBlogs = blogs.sort(compareBlogs);
  return sortedBlogs;
};

const App = () => {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);
  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    blogService.getAll().then((initialBlogs) => {
      // BLOGS ARE SORTED FIRST AND THEN SET IN THE STATE
      const sortedBlogs = sortBlogsAsPerMostLikedFirst(initialBlogs);
      setBlogs(sortedBlogs);
    });
  }, []);

  ...

  const increaseLikes = (blogToUpdate) => {
    ...

    blogService
      .update(blog.id, updatedBlog)
      .then((returnedBlog) => {
        const blogList = blogs.map((blog) => blog.id !== blogToUpdate.id ? blog : returnedBlog);
        // BLOGS ARE SORTED FIRST AND THEN UPDATED IN THE BLOGS STATE
        const sortedBlogs = sortBlogsAsPerMostLikedFirst(blogList);
        setBlogs(sortedBlogs);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        ...
      });
  };
  ...

  return (...)
};

export default App;

